# Grand Central Dispatch in Swift only works the first run

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I got a method which works like a refresher which uses the GCD pattern as shown below:

```
    func getStepsForTheWeek() {
    let concurrentQueue : dispatch_queue_t  = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

    dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, {

        // Create an array of Days.
        var days = [Day]()

        dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, {
            print("first")

            for day in 0...7 {

                let date = self.getDate(day)

                // Get the date the day after that day.
                let endDate = self.getDateDayAfter(date)

                // Create a Day.
                var day = Day(date: date)

                self.pedometer.queryPedometerDataFromDate(date, toDate: endDate, withHandler: {numberOfSteps, error in
                    print("fetching")

                    if error != nil {
                        print("There was an error requesting data from the pedometer: \(error)")
                    } else {
                        day.steps = numberOfSteps!.numberOfSteps as Int
                        days.append(day)
                    }
                })
            }
        })

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            print("second")

            self.historyViewController.days = days
            self.historyViewController.reloadHistory()
        })
    })
}
```

When the app starts the method works as it is intended to.
But when the app is in the background and when I'm going back to the app I got this Observer which calls the method again to refresh its content.

```
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "appBecomeActive", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil )
```

But everytime I do this the second code-block is running before the first one.
Any help?

Comment: depends whether whatever fetches your data is asynchronous or not whether the 2nd block will finish before the data is fetched, can you post some more code or tell us what you are using to fetch the data

Comment: I updated the question. I use it for query a stepcounter.

Comment: Why are you using dispatch_sync? dispatch_sync is asking for trouble unless you really, really know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should do the UI update in the completion handler of the pedometer query

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {

        self.pedometer.queryPedometerDataFromDate(date, toDate: endDate, withHandler: { numberOfSteps, error in
            if error != nil {
                print("There was an error requesting data from the pedometer: \(error)")
            } else {
                let numberOfStepsThisDay = numberOfSteps?.numberOfSteps as! Int

                day.steps = numberOfStepsThisDay
                days.append(day)
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.historyViewController.days = self.days
                self.historyViewController.reloadHistory()
            })
        })
    })
```

you should always update the UI in the completion handler of the method if it has one, since you dont know whether it could be asynchronous or not (usually would be asynchronous if using a completion handler), you can probably drop the outer dispatch_async if there is no other code in it besides the pedometer query

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank you very much. It works like a charm.

Comment: I'm sorry but this only solve half the problem.
    I need this method to fetch the steps for a whole week.
    
    I updated the question. Can you have a look at it?
    Because the query need to be running in a loop. And when that is done the other viewcontroller should reload.

This works on startup, but when coming back to the app the second dispatch runs before the fetching is finish.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it.
In the query I check if the array of days is filled (e.g size of 8). 
When filled the reload should be done. I also deleted all unnecessary sync-tasks. Much cleaner now. It was simpler than I thought.

```
    func getStepsForTheWeek() {

    // Create an array of Days.
    var days = [Day]()

    print("first")

    // Fetch the total steps per day for 8 days (0 - 7).
    for day in 0...7 {

        // Get days date from today.
        let date = self.getDate(day)

        // Get the date the day after that day.
        let endDate = self.getDateDayAfter(date)

        // Create a Day.
        var day = Day(date: date)


        // Query the Pedometer for the total steps of that day.
        self.pedometer.queryPedometerDataFromDate(date, toDate: endDate) {
            (data, error) -> Void in
            if(error == nil){

                print("fetching")

                day.steps = data!.numberOfSteps as Int
                days.append(day)

                if(days.count == 8){
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                        print("finished")

                        self.historyViewController.days = days
                        self.historyViewController.reloadHistory()
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to Fonix and gnasher729.